# Using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionNotifications and suspending notifications

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I'm struggling with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` on a separate thread.
I have the following class which overrides the `ObservavbleCollection` so that I can suspend notifications when doing bulk updates. In the constructor I also make a call to support modifying the collection on different thread using `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSyncronization`

The issue I have is when doing the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` not on the UI thread I get an exception (regular Add/Remove to the collection work). I thought `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSyncronization` enabled cross thread notifications?

```
public class ObservableDataCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool _suppressNotification = false;
    private object _lock = new object();

    public ObservableDataCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Items, _lock); }

    public ObservableDataCollection() { BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Items, _lock); }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }


    public void SuppressNotifications(bool suppressNotification)
    {
        _suppressNotification = suppressNotification;
        if (_suppressNotification == false)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Then when I make changes

```
// On UI thread
var synchronizedCollection = new ObservableDataCollection();
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(synchronizedCollection, synchronizedCollection.SyncLock);

// Background thread
syncronizedCollection.SupressNotifications(true);
synchronizedCollection.Clear(); 
synchronizedCollection.Add/Remove etc
syncronizedCollection.SupressNotifications(false); // throws
```

I had assumed that `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` would take care of dispatching `base.OnCollectionChanged` in my `SupressNotifications` call on the UI thread.

So I need to take care of dispatching it on the UI thread.

I know I have to call BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` from each UI thread.

The bigger question then becomes what happens and how do I manage notifications when the collection is bound on multiple UI threads?

Comment: All operation on an ObservableDataCollection must be done in the UI thread. That is how the ObservableDataCollection class is build. There is several ways of change, enhance or rebuild the ObservableDataCollection - you can find many of them here on Stackoverflow

Comment: I am pretty sure you mean `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`. Normally, the `INotifyCollectionChanged` must be raised raised on the UI thread _only if_ the UI thread is binding to the collection i.e. accessing the collections `CollectionView`. This behavior is true for every type of thread, since the `CollectionView` is `Dispatcher` affine. Calling `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` will takeover the responsibility to marshal collection changes to the UI thread. To tell you what you may have done wrong, you should show how you trigger the observed behavior.

Comment: Please show you how you trigger the exception. Your posted code is alright.  Mind that `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` _must_ be called on the thread that is associated with the `CollectionView` e.g. UI thread.

Comment: I have add some more details and expanded the question given your example - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I have said before, the method `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` must be called on the thread that the `CollectionView` of `ObservableDataCollection` is associated with.

`CollectionView` has `Dispatcher` affinity, which is the root of all problems and the reason you must marshal the`INotifyCollectionChanged` handler invocation to the correct `Dispatcher` thread. Taking care of this should fix your  problem.

The fact that you are calling `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` in the constructor may also be a reason that lead to the issue.
Consider a scenario, where the instance of the collection is created on a different thread than it is actually used: you are going to experience a cross-thread exception. It's best practice to let the user of your class handle this.

Another important point is that `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` is only applied to the `CollectionView` of the collection passed as the argument. This means you are currently synchronizing the view of the internal collection `Items`. This is not the view that is returned when setting up a `Binding` that has the owning `ObservableDataCollection` as `Binding.Source`. You are synchronizing the wrong collection view and must synchronize `ObservableDataCollection` instead:

```
public ObservableDataCollection() 
  => BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lock);
```

But since you should remove the call to `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` from the constructor and should expose the sync lock object:

```
public class ObservableDataCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public object SyncLock { get; } = new object();
    private bool _suppressNotification = false;

    public ObservableDataCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) {}    
    public ObservableDataCollection() {}
}
```

, the proper way to mark the collection as synchronized would be:

```
// On UI thread
var synchronizedCollection = new ObservableDataCollection();
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(synchronizedCollection, synchronizedCollection.SyncLock);

// Background thread
synchronizedCollection.Clear(); // Won't throw
```